# Logs not received on remote syslog server

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to centralize logs (`/var/log/secure` and `/var/log/messages`) from a Linux server (rsyslog) to a Solaris server (syslog).

My `rsyslog.conf` file:

```
#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none @logserver:514

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
authpriv.*      @logserver:514
# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  /var/log/maillog

# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
```

On Solaris I configured the server to accept logs:

```
svccfg -s system-log setprop config/log_from_remote = true
```

I restarted syslog and rsyslog, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is probably firewalled. Use the Solaris `snoop` command to see if data is coming in.

Comment: I checked with `snoop` command on port 514 and I receive data only from another Solaris(syslog) server.